# Lighttpd FastCGI PHP https - complete handshake with different certificates?

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd

Ok, I'm sure someone is going to tell me this is a really dumb idea but please humor me.

I have a php site that is hosted using Lighttpd.  I have multiple domains that resolve to my website (for example...mysite.com and mysite2.com).  These sites need to use https.

When either mysite.com or mysite2.com are requested I want my php page to respond with the correct certificate.  So, to clarify, when the browser gets the response from my php page it will not complain about the certificate because it will use the correct certificate.

Is this possible?  How?

Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time PHP is running the SSL handshake has already been completed by your web server, so there's no way it can do anything about the certificate.

If you're using name-based virtual hosting but you still want to use different SSL certificates, you can leverage on [`SNI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (an extension on SSL and TLS) which is supported by most browsers and web servers (requires OpenSSL >= 0.9.8), including Lighttpd.